# What is the best way to handle when a Jquery selector fails?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In the context of an ASP.NET application.
Is there a better way to handle this?
Surely javascript errors should never be shown to the end user, so what should we do?

```
function Save() 
{
     var ajaxForm = $('form#ajaxForm');
     if (ajaxForm.length == 0)
         console.error("Ajax for to submit not found, Save will not work!");
     else
        ajaxForm.trigger('submit');
}
```

Comment: Why would `form#ajaxForm` not exist? Is that element dynamically injected into the HTML?

Comment: it should always exist, what if a fellow developer accidentally changed the id of the form. The Save would never happen and I'm unsure how to detect it and tell the user something useful while reporting the issue in some way.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery handles errors gracefully. If you call any method on a selector which returned no elements, then you won't get any errors shown in the console.

You can safely reduce your code to the following, without fear of any errors:

```
function Save() {
    $('form#ajaxForm').trigger('submit');
}
```

Obviously, if you want to actually show the user a message when the element does not exist, then your `if` condition checking the `length` property of the jQuery object is the correct method to use.